# Use external javascript libraries for TVML based Apple TV apps?

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

Is it possible to load and use external javascript libraries for use on TVML Apple TV apps?

For example, can I load the Firebase js library and use it to fetch data? Or load lodash to use it's functions?

Comment: I am successfully using require by using browserfy. Go promises!

Comment: @mcabe could you possibly provide an example please?

Comment: Sure. I set up a [repo](https://github.com/mcabe/appletvmljs) which demos my architecture. But the list of it is I use npm to install any decencies and just require them and my view-controllers. browserify just bundles  my files.

Comment: @mcabe wow that's great! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, the architecture isn't great by any means but it should get you started

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can load external JavaScript libraries using the evaluateScript function.

```
evaluateScripts([“ARRAY OF JS URLS”], function(success) {

// do work here once the JavaScript files have been evaluated

})
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had luck using webpack to package all of my dependencies into a single minified application.js file. Webpack will handle bundling required commonjs modules and third-party libraries and you can use babel-loader to add missing es6 support (import/export, const/let, arrow functions, etc).

Here's my application.js:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
import Presenter from './presenter';
import ResourceLoader from './resourceLoader';

App.onLaunch = function(options) {
  let resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader(options.BASEURL);

  Presenter.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;

  let index = resourceLoader.loadResource(`${options.BASEURL}templates/Index.xml.js`, (resource) => {
    let doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
    doc.addEventListener('select', Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
  });
}
```

and my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/application.js",
  output: {
      path: __dirname + "/public/js",
      filename: "application.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: And how do you use safari web inspector to debug with webpack output js?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, using `evaluateScripts` is very limiting. However, I do have the same question as @zfu: how do you debug a webpack output?

Comment: @jpcarreira I'm able to debug web web inspector, just enable options `devtool: "inline-source-map"` in webpack's configuration.

Comment: Hey Cezary, How do you evaluate scripts in this case? What does your Resource Loader and Presenter do? Thanks

Comment: @cezary-wojtkowski Thank you for your post. I'm having an issue with Webpack that my `App` is exposed as a module instead of code that is executed. How did you workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/emadalam/tvml-catalog-using-atvjs

Refer to this port of the original sample code re-written using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework that is using external libraries like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/), [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) etc.